# Ionic 2 Storage - Adding Records

Tags: ionic-framework, nosql

I am new to the NoSQL world and since Ionic 2 by default supports simple key-value DB, I was to some help here.

My app has a very large form. How do I go about saving new records? How do I retrieve those particular records?

Currently, to save a new record, I am doing something like this:

```
save(data){
    let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
    this.storage.set('reports', newData);
}
```

The problem with this is it overwrites the record instead of inserting a new record.

I am retrieving records like this:

```
getData() {
    return this.storage.get('reports');  
}
```

How do I go about fetching a particular record using certain values in the stored JSON?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you would have to do is make reports as an array and set it to the storage.
everytime you need to insert a new record, do a

```
function(newData){
    var some_variable = storage.get('reports'); //get Existing Table
    some_variable.push(newData); //Inserts the new record to array
    storage.set('reports', some_variable); //Saves report with updated data
}
```

For getting a particular report alone, I hope you have some id or a unique attribute y which you can distinguish a report. Assuming you have the report json as below :

```
var report {id : "UniqueID", name : "A sample report json"}
```

Then to get the report,

```
function(reportId){
    var reports = this.storage.get('reports');//fetches your reports Array
    var wantedReport = {};//Variable to store the wanted report
    reports.forEach(function(r){ //Looping the array.You can use a forloop as well
        if(r.id === reportId){ //filtering for the wanted reportId
            wantedReport = r; // storing the report to variable
        }
    })
    return wantedReport; //Returning the report to the caller.
}
```

Alternatively, If you are used to Sql and want a Sql-like way of storing these data then you can install the [Sqlite cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) and store your data in a Sqlite DB.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I am way more comfortable working with SQL given my relational DB background but Ionic 2 doesn't support WebSQL anymore, which is deprecated and soon won't be supported by browsers. Although I am going to eventually deploy for iOS, I want to stick to using @ionic/storage, which is cross platform but requires you to go NoSQL.

Comment: Ionic defaults to webSql only when testing in browsers.. If you have installed Sqlite cordova plugin, then you get an actual Sqlite datastore in your app when you run it in your mobile.. but i guess ionic/storage is very simple and easy to learn once you get past the NoSql learning curve. :-)

Comment: Can you have a look at this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689516/ionic-2-and-json-data-addition

Thanks.