# Ionic 2 and JSON Data Addition

Tags: javascript, json, ionic2

I am working with Ionic 2 Storage to persist form data. I save the data like this:

```
this.storage.set(key, JSON.stringify(formData));
```

And I retrieve and attempt to update the data like this:

```
this.getReport(key).then((report) => {
  var objReport = JSON.parse(report);
  objReport.push(data); //this is the problem
  this.storage.set(pk, JSON.stringify(objReport));
});
```

getReport is just this:

```
getReport(key) {
  return this.storage.get(key);
}
```

So I know that .push is for arrays and not objects, but I don't think its efficient to do all this conversions because I am dealing with large objects.

**My question is:** what is the most efficient way to retrieve json from storage and append to it? It makes no sense to me that .parse returns an object if objects do not have a push method like arrays.

Here is the error:

> Runtime Error Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of
>   undefined

Comment: If your 'report' is stored as an 'json' object, you will get back an json Object after json.parse(). If you have stored 'report' as an 'Array' object, you will get back an Array Object after json.parse(). "object" in this context is a javascript object which can be in the format of an array or a normal object.

Answer (score 1):

what this error means is that, there are no records for that key at this moment.
So, you would have to do a check like this :

```
this.getReport(key).then((report) => {
  var objReport = [];//initialise empty Array
  if(report){ //if there is a record in that key location
     objReport = JSON.parse(report); //parse the record & overwrite objReport
  }
  objReport.push(data); //Now this push will happen regardless of report or not
  this.storage.set(pk, JSON.stringify(objReport));
});
```

Comment: Actually, the whole code block runs inside if (report) condition, I just excluded it to keep the questions focused.

So this is still a problem.

Comment: The answer still stands. If report = [Array of json], then .push() will works. Even otherwise we are initialising objReport = [Array]. So the push will still work and saves this new array to the location.

Comment: If you want a more granular control over the noSQL data, then you would have to go for a more comprehensive NoSQL storage like pouchDB.. I would recommend that / SQlite if you are going to store huge amount of data at the client side since this.storage by ionic uses the browser's localStorage which has  an upper limit of 10MB of data storage and the data can also be easily cleared/lost.

Comment: So the problem is with using stringify when storing? Even when I store them as objects, and get rid of stringify and parse, it doesn't work!

Regarding the storage space, Ionic 2 Storage uses SQLite (if native) and IndexedDB, WebSQL and LocalStorage (in that order) for web.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr with your code? Then, I will be able to help you out better..